Approximate Saturation of Jensen's Inequality
Let $f$ be a convex function and $X$ a random variable. Jensen's inequality states:
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\geq f(\mathbb{E}[X]).$$
When $f$ is an affine function, this inequality is saturated, i.e. it becomes an equality, simply via linearity of the expectation.
I am interested in cases where Jensen's inequality is nearly saturated. That is, if one has a function which is "nearly" affine, can one conclude that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\approx f(\mathbb{E}[X])?$$
I am not completely sure what the appropriate condition on $f$ ought to be to be considered "nearly" affine, but I was wondering if the following condition on the second derivatives of $f$ is sufficient for approximate saturation:
Let $f_k:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of convex (concave) functions such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k''(x)  = 0$, where convergence is uniform in $x$. Is this sufficient to conclude
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[f_k(X)] = \lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(\mathbb{E}[X])?$$

Since Jensen inequality gives an equality for an affine function, without loss of generality you can perturbate the functions $f_k$ by an affine function to assume f_k(0) = f_k'(0) =0. Integrating the uniform convergence hypothesis on $f_k''$, we get the locally uniform convergence $f_k \longrightarrow 0$. This proves your result in the case where $X$ is bounded.
If $X$ is not bounded but you assume $\mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$, the uniform bound on $f_k''$ implies $f_k(x) \le C x^2$ so you can apply the dominated convergence theorem  to get $\mathbb{E}[f_k(X)] \rightarrow 0 $, which implies the desired result.
